# Unable to separate variables from dataset

Tags: r

I am using the Dodgers.data dataset I am trying to read properly and it is only loading under two variables instead of 3. I try the sep command and can only do one or the other. If I add a "," I can separate time and car count, but time and date gets lumped together. Any advise will be grately appreciated!

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Dodgers+Loop+Sensor

```
dat_txt = ldply("Dodgers.data", read.table, sep = ",", fill=TRUE, header = TRUE)

dat_txt
View(dat_txt)
```

Comment: Download the file to your computer. First, click the "Data Folder", then on the next page, click on "Dodgers.data">   , this initiate the download to your PC.   Put file "Call2.data" on your desktop or into your r working directory.

Comment: If I look at the `Dodgers.data` file in a regular text editor, to me it is "clearly" two comma-separated columns: `4/10/2005 0:00,-1`. Yes, date and time get lumped together, that's a "timestamp", and is a common way to store data.

Comment: (BTW: don't use `ldply`, it is doing nothing for you here. And there is no header row in the file that I saw, so `header=FALSE`, too.)

Comment: Try `dat_txt <- within(dat_txt, { date <- gsub("\\s.*", "", V1); time <- gsub(".*\\s", "", V1); })` to get the date and time separated, but **really** you should just convert them to a `POSIXt` class with something like `dat_txt <- within(dat_txt, { timestamp <- as.POSIXct(V1, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"); })`. (There are many ways to do this, `within` is one, as is `transform` and many verbs within `dplyr` and `data.table`.)

Answer (score 0):

First, it's normal that you get only two columns when reading the files since there is only one comma per row. The first column is the part before the comma and the second column is the part after
Also, you do not have the column names as the first row so `header=FALSE`is the right choice, and it is easier to load it using `read_csv` function from `tidyr` for example.

```
library(readr)
dat_txt <- read_csv("Dodgers.data",col_names = c('datetime','count'))
```

To split the date and the time parts, I recommend to use the `lubridate`package to transform the `datetime`column from character to a datetime object, then you can create three columns containing the date and the hour and minutes parts

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
dat_txt <- dat_txt %>% mutate(datetime = mdy_hm(datetime),
               date=date(datetime),
               hour = hour(datetime),
               minute= minute(datetime))
```

Comment: There is no reason here for `ldply`. Will you consider not loading all of the `tidyverse` in your answer? There are some who may not have all of it installed (but have the one or two packages needed), and installing for just this answer is overkill. Just as we encourage questions to include a minimal working example without unnecessary packages, I suggest answers should be held to the same standard, and only include packages that are required. `dplyr` and `lubridate` should suffice here.